# javascript android doesnt work

Tags: javascript, android

I'm working on binding javascript and android.

The web view

```
visor.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
visor.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

My Web Interface:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showToast(String toast) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, toast+" cosas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            visor.loadUrl("www.google.com");
        }
    }
```

HTML load for android

```
<input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showAndroidToast(toast) {
        Android.showToast(toast);
    }
</script>
```

The execution works for toast but load url doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change your title to something which actually describes your problem.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html Provides an example that looks similar to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a URL has to be loaded after its first execution, it has to be loaded from a different thread like this:

```
    mWebView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://google.com");
        }
    });
```

And so in your case:

```
public class WebAppInterface {
        Context mContext;

        WebAppInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        @JavascriptInterface
        public void showToast(String toast) {
            Toast.makeText(mContext, toast+" cosas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            visor.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    visor.loadUrl("http://google.com");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!  after frist execution , in all situations we need loadurl on another thread?

Comment: Yes. In fact its better you use the same way every time you want to load a URL.

Comment: If you do so, you actually make sure that the main thread is never blocked.